Devcontainer leave terminal process running
I have a docker-compose stack running on a remote server with 5 services. On the server, the file structure looks like this:
.
├── devcontainers
│   ├── AssetCompiler
│   │   └── .devcontainer
│   │       ├── devcontainer.json
│   │       └── setup.sh
│   ├── DocumentStore
│   │   └── .devcontainer
│   │       ├── devcontainer.json
│   │       └── setup.sh
│   └── docker-compose.devcontainer.yml
├── docker-compose.override.yml
└── docker-compose.yml

To develop the application remotely, I connect to the remote sever in VS Code (using Remote-SSH), enter one of the devcontainer root folders (for instance devcontainers/DocumentStore) and execute Dev Containers: Reopen in Container from the VS Code Command Palette.
Both devcontainers use the same docker image which is based on the Microsoft dotnet devcontainer image.
#
# Use the devcontainer SDK as a basis
#
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/dotnet

# - Install additional packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        dumb-init \
        npm \
        ssh && \
    apt-get clean

WORKDIR /app

# - Expose the webserver port that we will be using to access the application
EXPOSE 4812 4813

# - Opt out of the MS telemetry function
ENV DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1

# - Use the polling file watcher
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true

ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "infinity"]

The devcontainer.json looks like this:
{
    "name": "DocumentStore",

    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../../../docker-compose.yml",
        "../../../docker-compose.override.yml",
        "../../docker-compose.devcontainer.yml"
    ],
    "service": "documentstore",

    "overrideCommand": false,
    
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",

    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {},
            "extensions": [
                "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
                "ms-dotnettools.csdevkit",
                "augustocdias.tasks-shell-input"
            ]
        }
    },
    "shutdownAction": "none",

    "postCreateCommand": ["/.devcontainer/setup.sh"],

    "remoteUser": "1000"
}

The setup.sh script clones the source code if it does not exist and should only run when the container is spinning up for the first time. Like this:
#!/bin/bash

rootpathos="/workspace"

if [ ! -d "$rootpathos/.git" ]; then
    echo "=> Cloning the repository <="

    cd "$rootpathos"

    git clone --recurse-submodules ssh://<<path to repro>> .
    git submodule update --init --recursive
    git submodule update --recursive

    echo "=> Done cloning repository <="

    echo "=> Setting up additional components <="

    npm install

    echo "=> Done setting up additional components <="
else
    echo "=> All has been setup already <="
fi

In the different docker-compose.yml files, I do not overwrite the entrypoint of the container.
When my devcontainer launches, I need to start the dotnet app like this dotnet watch run --project DocumentStore
Can you help me with the following:
(1) Terminal process stops when I exit the devcontainer using "Close Remote Connection"
How can I leave my dotnet process running in the container when I close the remote connection? With the current setup, the dotnet process seems to stop immediately when I close the connection.
(2) Setup.sh script asks me to hit a key with this message "Done. Press any key to close the terminal."
It's great that I can see the progress of the setup script, but is there any way that the startup process can continue without having to hit a key?
(3) Is there any way to start the dotnet process (command dotnet watch run --project DocumentStore) when the container launches for the first time (after completion of setup.sh)?
Your input would be greatly appreciated!
